# IEEEremainder(double, double) is undefined for the type Math

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to use `java.lang.Math.IEEEremainder(double f1, double f2)` in GWT. But I got below exception.

> [ERROR] Line 1119: The method IEEEremainder(double, double) is
>   undefined for the type Math

I attempted to execute this code : `angle = Math.IEEEremainder(angle, 360.0);`

How to solve this issue in GWT?. If its not solve then what would be the alternative way to achieve the same functionality of `Math.IEEEremainder` this method.

Comment: please post your code?

Comment: @thegauravmahawar Please check my update question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JRE Emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_lang) this function is not supported in GWT.

So if you really need it and can't work around it, you will need to implement it yourself.

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to limit the angle to 360 degrees.
You could achieve that with this code:

```
/**
 * Normalize a degree value.
 * @param d value
 * @return 0&lt;=value&lt;=360
 */
public static double normalizeDegrees(double d)
{
    while (d < 0)
    {
        d += 360;
    }
    while (d > 360)
    {
        d -= 360;
    }
    return d;
}
```

If you just got positive numbers, you can even skip the upper `while`-Block.

Comment: Actually I want to use IEEEremainder method but In I cant use it due to JRE emulation. So is there any alternative way to achieve the same functionality in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have the [IEEEremainder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#IEEEremainder-double-double-) method in GWT, implement it like that:

```
/**
 * Computes the remainder operation on two arguments as prescribed by the IEEE 754 standard. The remainder value is
 * mathematically equal to <code>f1&nbsp;-&nbsp;f2</code>&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;<i>n</i>, where <i>n</i> is the
 * mathematical integer closest to the exact mathematical value of the quotient {@code f1/f2}, and if two
 * mathematical integers are equally close to {@code f1/f2}, then <i>n</i> is the integer that is even. If the
 * remainder is zero, its sign is the same as the sign of the first argument. Special cases:
 * <ul>
 * <li>If either argument is NaN, or the first argument is infinite, or the second argument is positive zero or
 * negative zero, then the result is NaN.
 * <li>If the first argument is finite and the second argument is infinite, then the result is the same as the first
 * argument.
 * </ul>
 * @param f1 the dividend.
 * @param f2 the divisor.
 * @return the remainder when {@code f1} is divided by {@code f2}.
 */
public static double IEEEremainder(double f1, double f2)
{
    double div = Math.round(f1 / f2);
    return f1 - (div * f2);
}
```

*(I added this as a new comment to show the syntax highlighting).*